# How to generate thumbnails from inputStream in Java using GraphicsMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I am trying to generate Thumbnails for an input stream using **GraphicsMagick** in a java application.

I am using ProcessBuilder to invoke convert command (which needs to work on both windows and Linux)

*Issue is* - Thumbnails fails to generate in most of the cases.

The command which I have created works on linux machines most of the time, but fails on windows machine.

I have tried using ImageMagick and that helps on Windows machines as well, but it is asked from us to work with GraphicsMagick, so stuck with that.

```
    public static ByteArrayInputStream createThumbnail(InputStream inputStream, int thumbnailHeight) throws IOException
    {
        /*The below comment is to test the direct use of imagemagic library for thumbnail generation
        * ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("magick ", "-", "-geometry", "x" + thumbnailHeight, "jpeg:-");
        * http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html
        **/       
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert", "-", "-geometry", "x" + thumbnailHeight, "jpeg:-");
        pb = pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();

        try (InputStream imageInputStream = inputStream; OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream())
        {
            IOUtils.copy(imageInputStream, stdin);
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream thumbnailInputStream = null;

        try (InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream(); ByteArrayOutputStream thumbnailOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            IOUtils.copy(stdout, thumbnailOutputStream);
            thumbnailInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(thumbnailOutputStream.toByteArray());
        }
        try
        {
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            checkExitCode(process, exitCode);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            LOGGER.error("THUMBNAIL:: Error getting process state: ", ie);
        }

        return thumbnailInputStream;
    }
```

Input should be an input stream along with Height of the thumbnail desired. 
Output should be valid output stream which can then be written to a jpeg file.

**InputStream is provided as input for the fact that the thumbnail can be for anything, photo/gif/video**

Comment: `but fails on windows machine` - how exactly does it fail? Did you try it from command line?

Comment: In java code it fails with ```pipe stream closed``` error @Piro

However it does convert properly using this command 
```convert -size 120x120 cockatoo.jpg -resize 120x120 +profile "*" thumbnail.jpg```

Comment: @Piro even the command ```convert Cuckoo_Bird.jpg -geometry x256 jpeg:-``` indeed gives me back the stream printed in the console.

**But here I have used a photo and in code input is being passed as an input stream**